# dockerized Keycloak as Idp and Idp Broker (same address and port)

Tags: docker, keycloak, idp, oidc-identity-brokering

I've started my dockerized keycloak on port 8180 with the command:

```
docker run -p 8180:8080 -e KEYCLOAK_USER=admin -e KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=admin -e KEYCLOAK_HOSTNAME=localhost quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:16.1.0 -Dkeycloak.profile.feature.upload_scripts=enabled
```

So as admin I've created 2 realms (in the same keycloak instance):

- Tenant1
- Silver

In **Tenant1** I've defined a client (public) connected to a Angular app (It works) and an GITHUB Identity Provider (It works also)

In **Silver** Realm I've defined a client "silverBroker" as confidential...connected to a Angular App (it works)

My purpose is to use the silverBroker as Identity Broker for tenant1 as explained in different websites (but the keycloak instances were different), for example:
https://medium.com/keycloak/keycloak-as-an-identity-broker-an-identity-provider-af1b150ea94

The flow seems to work....I access to login page of tenant1...I can use the silverBroker
[selecting keycloak oidc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ce5E9.png) (keycloak-oidc)
It correctly redirect to silver realm login ... I insert the right username and password but after that I've revceived the error: "Unexpected error when authenticating with identity provider" in Tenant1, [the http error is 502 Bad Gateway](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D92uq.png)
..on the container logs I've this stacktrace:

```
11:08:59,680 ERROR [org.keycloak.broker.oidc.AbstractOAuth2IdentityProvider] (default task-23) Failed to make identity provider oauth callback: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:8180 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)
        at org.apache.httpcomponents.core//org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:156)
        at org.apache.httpcomponents.core//org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:376)
        at org.apache.httpcomponents.core//org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:393)
        at org.apache.httpcomponents.core//org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
        at org.apache.httpcomponents.core//org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186)
        at org.apache.httpcomponents.core//org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
        at org.apache.httpcomponents.core//org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
        at org.apache.httpcomponents.core//org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
        at org.apache.httpcomponents.core//org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
        at org.apache.httpcomponents.core//org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:108)
        at org.apache.httpcomponents.core//org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
        at org.keycloak.keycloak-server-spi-private@16.1.0//org.keycloak.broker.provider.util.SimpleHttp.makeRequest(SimpleHttp.java:277)
        at org.keycloak.keycloak-server-spi-private@16.1.0//org.keycloak.broker.provider.util.SimpleHttp.asResponse(SimpleHttp.java:216)
        at org.keycloak.keycloak-server-spi-private@16.1.0//org.keycloak.broker.provider.util.SimpleHttp.asString(SimpleHttp.java:208)
        at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@16.1.0//org.keycloak.broker.oidc.AbstractOAuth2IdentityProvider$Endpoint.authResponse(AbstractOAuth2IdentityProvider.java:500)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:170)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:130)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.internalInvokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:660)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTargetAfterFilter(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:524)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.lambda$invokeOnTarget$2(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:474)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:364)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:476)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:434)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceLocatorInvoker.invokeOnTargetObject(ResourceLocatorInvoker.java:192)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceLocatorInvoker.invoke(ResourceLocatorInvoker.java:152)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceLocatorInvoker.invokeOnTargetObject(ResourceLocatorInvoker.java:183)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceLocatorInvoker.invoke(ResourceLocatorInvoker.java:141)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceLocatorInvoker.invoke(ResourceLocatorInvoker.java:32)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:492)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$invoke$4(SynchronousDispatcher.java:261)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$preprocess$0(SynchronousDispatcher.java:161)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:364)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.preprocess(SynchronousDispatcher.java:164)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:247)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:249)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:60)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:55)
        at javax.servlet.api@2.0.0.Final//javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:590)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
        at org.keycloak.keycloak-wildfly-extensions@16.1.0//org.keycloak.provider.wildfly.WildFlyRequestFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(WildFlyRequestFilter.java:41)
        at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@16.1.0//org.keycloak.services.filters.AbstractRequestFilter.filter(AbstractRequestFilter.java:43)
        at org.keycloak.keycloak-wildfly-extensions@16.1.0//org.keycloak.provider.wildfly.WildFlyRequestFilter.doFilter(WildFlyRequestFilter.java:39)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
        at org.wildfly.security.elytron-web.undertow-server@1.10.1.Final//org.wildfly.elytron.web.undertow.server.ElytronRunAsHandler.lambda$handleRequest$1(ElytronRunAsHandler.java:68)
        at org.wildfly.security.elytron-base@1.18.1.Final//org.wildfly.security.auth.server.FlexibleIdentityAssociation.runAsFunctionEx(FlexibleIdentityAssociation.java:103)
        at org.wildfly.security.elytron-base@1.18.1.Final//org.wildfly.security.auth.server.Scoped.runAsFunctionEx(Scoped.java:161)
        at org.wildfly.security.elytron-base@1.18.1.Final//org.wildfly.security.auth.server.Scoped.runAs(Scoped.java:73)
        at org.wildfly.security.elytron-web.undertow-server@1.10.1.Final//org.wildfly.elytron.web.undertow.server.ElytronRunAsHandler.handleRequest(ElytronRunAsHandler.java:67)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.RedirectDirHandler.handleRequest(RedirectDirHandler.java:68)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:117)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
        at io.undertow.core@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.core@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
        at io.undertow.core@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.security.elytron-web.undertow-server-servlet@1.10.1.Final//org.wildfly.elytron.web.undertow.server.servlet.CleanUpHandler.handleRequest(CleanUpHandler.java:38)
        at io.undertow.core@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@26.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
        at io.undertow.core@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@26.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.SendErrorPageHandler.handleRequest(SendErrorPageHandler.java:52)
        at io.undertow.core@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:275)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:79)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:134)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:131)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@26.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1544)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@26.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1544)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@26.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1544)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@26.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1544)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:255)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:79)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:100)
        at io.undertow.core@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:387)
        at io.undertow.core@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:852)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
        at org.jboss.xnio@3.8.5.Final//org.xnio.XnioWorker$WorkerThreadFactory$1$1.run(XnioWorker.java:1280)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
        at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:399)
        at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:242)
        at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:224)
        at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:609)
        at org.apache.httpcomponents.core//org.apache.http.conn.socket.PlainConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainConnectionSocketFactory.java:75)
        at org.apache.httpcomponents.core//org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142)
        ... 92 more

11:08:59,688 WARN  [org.keycloak.events] (default task-23) type=IDENTITY_PROVIDER_LOGIN_ERROR, realmId=tenant1, clientId=tenant1Client, userId=null, ipAddress=172.17.0.1, error=identity_provider_login_failure, code_id=99b2957b-8d63-491c-bf52-d548bfa6877c, authSessionParentId=99b2957b-8d63-491c-bf52-d548bfa6877c, authSessionTabId=l6P0OWdhgvc
```

Is it possible that the problem is that both Idp & Broker run on the same instance (localhost:8180) of keycloak? Is it a problem of the dockerized keycloak? Is there a solution to run Idp & Broker on the same dockerized keycloak?

Thanx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`localhost` in the container is not a `localhost` on the host. Don't use `localhost` but `fully-qualified domain name`, which will resolve to correct Keycloak instance IP.